# Search: Exclude List Link but not List Items from Search Results

Tags: search

Is it possible to exclude the link to a list but still include its items in search results?  For instance, can I exclude the actual link to a document library (say `http://intranet/documents`) but still include the documents within the library (`http://intranet/documents/file.docx`)?  And if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Lists / Document Libraries are displayed to end users via List Views, and list views are just ASPX pages with list web parts. You can [choose whether to include the contents of ASPX pages in search results](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-content-to-be-searchable-HA010379092.aspx#_Toc277075192) however this is site collection wide setting and I do not know it will work for your scenario. These are the available options:

- Do not index Web Parts if this site
  contains fine-grained permissions
- Always index all Web Parts on this
  site
- Never index any Web Parts on
  this site